# Joint optimization - Feature extraction and a classifier

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am dealing with a classification problem and high dimensional data. I am using a feature extraction method ( PCA - Principle Component Analysis) followed by a Support Vector Machine (SVM). I just wonder if there is a way that I can jointly optimize both (PCA and SVM) so that I can keep the features that improve the performance of SVM.

Does anyone have any idea if there is way to do this (joint optimization) in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of the sklearn pipeline. Jointly optimizing PCA components and SVM parameters can be done using model selection tools like cross-validation or similar. The User Guide has more information. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#pipeline

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sycorax. That is what I was looking for. I will definitely give it a try.